# How to root CovrWare Android phone?

Tags: rooting, root-access, security, android-10, bloatware

**NOTE: This is a very specific question on manufacturer name of the Android phone I am talking about...**

Hey, guys, I am needing to try and root a CovrWare manufacturer-made Android phone, from https://covrware.com, as I think there could be lots of system-based bloatware, so I am hoping to root this type of phone for this security purpose. Any help and instructions to root a CovrWare phone would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did I really miss something, or isn't CovrWare just a smartphone case? I don't see anywhere where I can buy Android *phones* from there.

Comment: Maybe by "rooting" he means "digging" under the cover?

Comment: No. I mean to unlock the whole CovrWare's phone's OS, by rooting the OS on the phone, as in, unlocking the Android root user.

Comment: shut down device completely. hold *Volume Down + Power* keys until you can see bootloader/fastboot/download mode. connect device to PC and install [usb drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb). download [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) and navigate into folder where fastboot binary is. from cmd line type *'fastboot getvar all'* copy & paste that info into your question for further help. in case fastboot not available upload a picture of that phone screen in download mode instead

Comment: please note fastboot mode is not available for samsung devices (they have odin mode instead)